# How to pick up data from row and put it into tPostgresqlInput?

Tags: talend

I have a requets which giving me an ids. I need to iterate them into another request, so I have a sheme like this: [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82ufy.png)

In tPostgresqlInput I have this code `rc.id = upper('18ce317b-bf69-4150-b880-2ab739eab0fe')` , but instead of id I need to put smthn like `globalMap.get(row4.id)`. How did I do this?

Comment: can you give us the content of the postgresinput you have please?

Comment: Yep:
`FROM table
         LEFT JOIN table on parameter
         JOIN table on parameter
WHERE 1=1
AND column = 'content'
AND (upper(rc.id).equals upper('""+(globalMap.get("row4.id")) +"'"))`

Comment: Also talend giving me a compilation error with last string of code, which is "Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a syntax issue

Try with :

```
"select * FROM table  LEFT JOIN table  on parameter          JOIN table on parameter 
WHERE 1=1 AND 
column = 'content' 
AND upper(rc.id) =  upper('"+((String)globalMap.get("row4.id")) +"')"
```

- Expressions in tDBInput should always begin and end with double quotes.
- Don't forget to cast globalMap.get() with the type of your element (here I put `String`)
- `.equals` is not a DB function but a java function. I have replaced it with '='

Let me know if it's better